# Pausing my game issue in ActionScript 3

Tags: events, actionscript, pausing-execution

In my game I'm trying to add a Pause function, pressing P key. It works but the problem is that if the mouse stands still and I press P key, nothing happens but while I move the mouse it fastly works. to resume there is no problem. How can I fix that, to let it work without moving the mouse?
Here is the code

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, pauseGame);
function pauseGame(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
     if(!gamePaused && (e.keyCode == 80)){
     rect_Darken.x = STAGE_CENTER.x;
     rect_Darken.y = STAGE_CENTER.y;
     txt_Pause.x = STAGE_CENTER.x;
     txt_Pause.y = STAGE_CENTER.y;
     gamePaused = true;
     stage.frameRate = 0;
     }else if(e.keyCode == 80){
     stage.frameRate = 24;
     rect_Darken.x = 270;
     rect_Darken.y = 670;
     txt_Pause.x = 270;
     txt_Pause.y = 670;
     gamePaused = false;
     }
}
```

Comment: Random idea...is the stage somehow losing focus if the mouse stops moving? Not likely, I know, but a possibility. I can't see anything else wrong with the code off the top of my head, here. (Thus why I'm not answering properly.)

Comment: it looks like you said, but I don't know what it causes it...

Comment: try adding event listener to main application and see if it works

Comment: what you mean for main application? it already is

Comment: what a strange problem... could you try something for me? replace `stage.frameRate = 0` with `stage.stop()`, and `stage.frameRate = 24` with `stage.play()`, and see if anything changes